# graphviz let edges in opposite directions overlap

Tags: graphviz, dot

there are a lot of questions where 
A->B
B->A 
seem to overlap in a DOT graph but they shouldn't. Which seems not to happen anymore since recent graphviz versions.

But I'd like exactly that.

How can I turn this "feature or bug or what ever" back on?

Thanks 4 the help